# Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, webstore

Is there a way to convert my Android app for the Chrome web store? If not, has anyone seen any good tutorials for starting with that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There is not that much common between the Android Application and the Chrome Web Store. Does your Android Application use HTML5? You will probably just need a set of resource files to define your HTML application as a Chrome Web Store application so that it can be found and bookmarked and easily shared between different Chrome instances.

http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/

Answer (score 0):

From brief research I haven't found any simple way to go from android to chrome web store. It appears that the chrome web store has the same content that you would find on web pages, instead better integrated to chrome. I would recommend reading about how to make a chrome web app along with web development.

Answer (score 0):

They are too different to convert.  The reason is in most apps there are too many aspects you could not convert like accelerometer and multi touch gestures.